# MS Excel: combine tables from external sources with new data and keep refresh ability

Tags: excel, datatable, reference, refresh, datasource

To be able to use structural references later on for the WHOLE combined dataset:

[image]

I have a table that is linked to another workbook, starting in cell C1: ... . Now in this new workbook, I add two columns (A and B). Can I integrate this with the table from the other workbook, WHILST keeping the possibility to refresh/update that table I now have, if the source data changes?

I want to later use formulas like = sumproduct(Table1[title1];Table1[title3]) etc. So that if the order ever changes, I reference by column name (year) instead of absolute references. Also, when new rows are added, they are included automatically in my range.

Comment: If both data set are associated with an Excel Table, I think you can achieve that, every time the source table is updated you will get the destination information in the other table also updated. This is my understanding, did you try that?

Comment: Thx. Not yet. First two columns are not from another table.